# How to open a url with a #token in the browser

Tags: android, url, browser, url-rewriting, android-intent

When i do this

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://myapplication.com#myToken")));

'myToken' is lost.

Is this normal?

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: it seems that this occurs in the very specific case of redirection+token. replace my domain name by the real server fixed the problem, but is less pretty.

Comment: How are you doing a redirect? Is it possible your redirection code doesn't preserve the hash? (That said, avoiding unnecessary redirects is typically a good thing from a latency perspective).

Comment: i suppose my domain provider (wich is GANDI) does the redirect. In a browser, i can paste a full url with the domain, and the token is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You need a slash before the hash.